# Privacy Page in Multiple languages default language should be changed by users default language SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, development, office-365, out-of-the-box

We have almost 9 different languages in SharePoint according to location they use. I created a privacy page using html id for different languages but when the user log in it should open in their default language is it possible to achieve this requirement.Right now i kept English as the default one and they need to change the language if they want to see in different language?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a third-party tool like PointFire to show users pages and other content in their preferred language, but I assume you want to do this with SharePoint alone.

On the site where your privacy page is located, click on (gear) -> Site settings -> Language settings and select the site's 8 alternate languages and save.  This will activate the Multilingual User Interface for the site and when a user goes to that page it will set the language according to their User Profile language or their browser language that matches one of the site languages.

You then have a few choices:
1) Create 9 resx files with the strings of that page in all the languages you need and use C# to generate the page using those tokens

2) Like above, but just refer to the tokens in the aspx file, without any C# code
" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/>

3) Use JavaScript to change the html in the page based on the current language.  One popular way is to create multiple .js files and then load the correct one using the language.  For instance, create js files named Resources.nn-NN.js where nn-NN is the language code, each of which will contain values for the same variables, like "localizedheading" and have this in the aspx page:

' EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode' />.js">

the aspx can also contain a string replacement script like

window.onload = function () {
   document.getElementById("heading").innerText = localizedheading;
  }